# Counting node items in a linked list

Tags: nodes

Here is my program essentially, besides the "add" functions. The numItems function is supposed to receive 'item' as input and look through each Players things, and add up the amount of the item (if it's there). So, my problem is, say Player 1 has 3 dogs, Players 2 had 5 dogs, the function will only count 3 and then finish. When I tried to debug it with a printf that prints what item the 'iptr' is on, I get a seg fault right when it finds that second occurence of dog. I just feel like there's gotta be a simple solution to this.

```
typedef struct item {
char *name;
int count;
struct item *next;
} Items;

typedef struct player {
char *name;
Items *things;
struct player *next;
} Players;

int numItems(Players *list, char *item) {
    Players * ptr = list;
    Items* iptr = ptr->things;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        while(iptr != NULL ) {
            if(strcmp(iptr->name, item) == 0) {
                printf("first if: %s", iptr->name);
            }
            else {
                i++;
            } 
            iptr = iptr->next;
         }


       ptr = ptr->next;
     }
return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`iptr` should be re-initialized for each new non-NULL value of `ptr`.

Comment: So `iptr=ptr->things` right? If I add this directly after `ptr = ptr->next` within the `ptr` loop, I get an immediate seg fault. Is that where it should be added?

Comment: Try initializing it at the top of the pointer loop, where you know `ptr` is not null.